# How to know id of the div drag origin and id of the div drag relase?

Tags: jquery

I drag element1 from box2 to box3, I would like to detect the id of the start of the drag and the id of the end of the drag, how can I do?:

````
<div id="contenitore">
    <div id="box1">
    </div>

    <div id="box2">
        <span class="draggable" id="element1">element1</span>
    </div>
    
    <div id="box3">
    </div>
</div> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: '#imageboundary', axis: "x" });
        
        $("#contenitore").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) { 
            
                console.log(ui.draggable.attr("id")); // id of the item being dragged
                console.log(???); // id of the div drag origin????
                console.log(???); // id of the div drag relase????
                
            }
        });
        
    });
</script>```
````

Comment: And the question/problem is? Have you done any debugging/testing (`console.log(event, this)`) to try to find the info yourself?

Comment: Reading the data in console.log (event.target) I tried to figure out where the id was, initially I thought it was event.target.firstElementChild.id but it's not.